# Como passar um DataTable para o ReportViewer?

Tags: c#, datatable, reportviewer

Recebo a consulta do banco de dados em uma DataTable, preciso passar o datatable para uma tablix no reportviewer por código, porém quando executo a tablix retorna em branco, pesquisei em vários lugares e não encontrei um método ágil para fazer isso, segue o código...

```
private void frmRel_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.report.RefreshReport();

        DataTable dt = RelatoriosModel.PesquisaTodos(); // RETORNA A TABELA DA CONSULTA NO SERVIDOR

        ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource();

        this.report.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "CifalApp.Logistica.Relatorios.Relatorio.rdlc";

        reportDataSource.Name = "DataSet1";
        reportDataSource.Value = dt;

        this.report.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);
        this.report.RefreshReport();
    }
```

[image: Imagem do RDLC]

Comment: Mas esse tablix está puxando seus dados do "DataSet1"?

Comment: Não existe nada no DataSet1

Comment: E de onde o tablix está puxando os dados para renderizar o report então?]

Comment: Essa é a questão, não sei como fazer o tablix puxar os dados da datatable, ou passar a datatable pro tablix, estou tentando fazer isso sem usar um DataSet tipado, dessa forma que está acima foi apenas para testes

Comment: Então seu trabalho começa em montar o relatório primeiro e depois popular o dataset para exibir seus dados. De que adianta você mandar um conjunto de dados para ele se ele não tem nenhuma estrutura esperando essa carga?